# What is the fastest way to compose a dataframe from select elements of a json object?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a large, multi-faceted json file that I have pulled from an API.  For help in understanding the structure, it is composed with the following "levels":

1. player
2. game
3. player details within the game

I am looking to create the structure at the game level incorporating the details found at that lowest layer (e.g. the type of player attributes utilized in the game).  As a Python / json newbie, I have a list of attributes that I am looking for in the json.  The difficulty, however, is in building a dataframe with the attributes (indicator variables), I am needing to loop through the 3 levels, and to make things worse still, then looping through the json elements searching for the existence of the attributes.

It is not uniformly an indicator variable build, however.  In some cases, I am looking for categorical elements as well.

Having improved some of my code previously by building the dataframe from numpy arrays / lists as a final step, I am still "stuck" at the need to loop through the code.  As an added challenge, I am trying to create the list / numpy array variables at runtime since I'm pulling the indicator variables from a master dictionary.

```
var_list = ['Archers', 'Arrows', 'Baby_Dragon']  # list of variables to search in the 3rd level of the json output

json sample:
[{'type': 'PvP', 'battleTime': '20201226T094614.000Z', 'isLadderTournament': False, 'arena': {'id': 54000050, 'name': 'Legendary Arena'}, 'gameMode': {'id': 72000044, 'name': 'game_mode_made_up'}, 'deckSelection': 'collection', 'team': [{'tag': '#someid001', 'name': 'player_name01', 'startingTrophies': 6792, 'trophyChange': 38, 'crowns': 3, 'kingTowerHitPoints': 1992, 'princessTowersHitPoints': [2922], 'clan': {'tag': '#someid002', 'name': 'player_name02', 'badgeId': 16000011}, 'cards': [{'name': 'Inferno Dragon', 'id': 26000037, 'level': 5, 'starLevel': 3, 'maxLevel': 5, 'iconUrls': {'medium': 'https://web_photo.png'}}, {'name': 'Lumberjack', 'id': 26000035, 'level': 5, 'starLevel': 1, 'maxLevel': 5, 'iconUrls': {'medium': 'https://web_photo.png'}}]]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would help if you post your code and the full json response. What output do you want? Data frame? Arrays? If you know what you want mock that up too. Thx.

Comment: @JonathanLeon I have replaced this with a more specific question with added details.  Thanks for your consideration!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65466949/how-to-quickly-create-a-two-dimension-numpy-array-from-json-elements

Comment: Thx. Looks like you are getting answers already. If they work please give that person credit. Cheers.