# How to quickly create a two dimension numpy array from json elements?

Tags: python, json, numpy

I have nested json data that resembles the following:

```
[{'game':'001', 'animals': [{'name':'Dog', 'colour':'Red'}, {'name':'Horse', 'age':'6'},{'name':'Ostrich', 'location':'Africa'}]},{'game':'002', 'animals': [{'name':'Cat', 'colour':'Green'}, {'name':'Bison', 'location':'North America'},{'name':'Parrot', 'location':'Southeast Asia'}]}]
```

My objective is to create an indicator array entry for each animal (contained in 'name') corresponding to items in the variable "animal_list":

```
animal_list = ['Bison', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephants', 'Horse', 'Ostrich', 'Parrot']
```

So the desired structure would resemble (expressed as a csv...but this is illustrative only since an numpy positional array is what i'm seeking):

```
Game, Bison, Cat, Dog, Elephants, Horse, Ostrich, Parrot
"001",0,0,1,0,1,1,0
"002",1,1,0,0,0,0,1
```

I have traditionally formed this using a "double-loop" - first on 'game' items; followed by an inner loop that scans through the 'name' items.  Problem is, I have a long json list and it is taking hours to run.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide the code to your current approach.

Comment: its still seems invalid

Comment: Why not use pandas?

Comment: If you show us your traditional method it would be easier to suggest improvements.  It also makes testing easier.

Comment: `json` is a string; `loads` makes a dictionary.  There are only 2 ways to access dictionary elements - by key indexing or via `items` lists. `numpy` does not have an magic to do either of these faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the pandas version of the table.

You can always refer to the `ndarray` as `df.values`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [{'game': '001', 'animals': [{'name':'Dog', 'colour':'Red'}, {'name':'Horse', 'age':'6'},{'name':'Ostrich', 'location':'Africa'}]},
        {'game': '002', 'animals': [{'name':'Cat', 'colour':'Green'}, {'name':'Bison', 'location':'North America'},{'name':'Parrot', 'location':'Southeast Asia'}]}]
animal_list = ['Bison', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Elephants', 'Horse', 'Ostrich', 'Parrot']

games = [d['game'] for d in data]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(games), len(animal_list))),
                  index=games, columns=animal_list)

for ix, g in enumerate(games):
    a = [a['name'] for a in data[ix]['animals']]
    df.loc[g, a] = 1

print(df)


       Bison  Cat  Dog  Elephants  Horse  Ostrich  Parrot
001    0.0  0.0  1.0        0.0    1.0      1.0     0.0
002    1.0  1.0  0.0        0.0    0.0      0.0     1.0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  Much more elegant than the loop I am using.  A question - I have been under the impression that dataframe lookups are slow.  Might it be faster to use a numpy array and append?

Comment: basically u are right. but in your case because the original data is labeled by strings  and not by positions, you will have to manually convert the labels to indexes. This will probably cost you more and will be less elegant.